# Why negative lookahead is resulting in matches when combined with \b \w. Is there a way to solve this in one pattern?

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I have the following patter:
`(?!.*(land|building).*)(\b\w*area( |_)?code\w*\b).*`

The goal for this pattern is to match all rows with area code but exclude when the row has land or building. For example, given the below dataset, only the 4 top ones would have anything matching it, all the others would be ignored:

##### Should match:

```
area code
area_code
state_area_code
employee_area_code
```

##### Should not match:

```
land area code
land_area code
land area_code
land_area_code
area code land
area code_land
area_code land
area_code_land
building area_code
area_code building
```

Unfortunately, the ones with spaces before the word "area" are being also selected. I'm not able to figure out why it is not working on these cases and how to change the regex to ignore these 3 while still working for the correct ones:

```
land area code
land area_code
building area_code
```

I tried changing the look ahead by look behind, using a combination of patterns and replacing `\b` and `\w` by `.*` or adding `\s` and there is always some mismatches.

Comment: Are you coding this in Ruby?

Comment: this is pattern is part of a generic set of regexes consumed by different technologies. But mostly of the consumers are using python and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a start anchor `^`:

```
^(?!.*(land|building).*)(\b\w*area( |_)?code\w*\b).*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/MFc9PguHvizYuJ).

Without `^` the match can begin part-way through, at a point *after* the parts you want to exclude.

Comment: Adding an anchor as you suggested, will make all the "should match one" being ignored. I tried adding anchors between the word boundary too and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand. This regex matches all your "should match" examples and doesn't match any of your "should not match" examples, so it therefore answers your question as stated. Please edit your question to explain in detail what more there is to your problem.

Comment: I tried with a different tester and it worked this time. For some reason, on regextester.com nothing was selected while using regex101 worked. When I used in my code using re lib it worked too. Thank you for your help and quick response :)

Comment: One more example that is not being selected is if I replace underscore by space for the first word. For example, "state area_code". This one should match but it is not. Any suggestion?

Comment: This one worked for this example: ^(?!.*(land|building).*)(\b\w*( )?area( |_)?code\w*\b).*